cound not find command “deb” in ubuntu 22.04
Currently working on ubuntu 22.04 system, and installing mongodb package with a command -
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse

cound not find command “deb”，do you mean：

  command 'den' from snap den (1.2.0-0)
  command 'dub' from snap dub (1.19.0)
  command 'dab' from deb bsdgames (2.17-28build1)
  command 'derb' from deb icu-devtools (66.1-2ubuntu2.1)
  command 'dub' from deb dub (1.19.0-1build2.1)
  command 'dep' from deb go-dep (0.5.4-3ubuntu0.1)
  command 'dex' from deb dex (0.8.0-2)
  command 'debc' from deb devscripts (2.20.2ubuntu2)
  command 'debi' from deb devscripts (2.20.2ubuntu2)
  command 'edb' from deb edb-debugger (1.0.0-1build3)
  command 'deb3' from deb quilt (0.65-3)

how would I solve this issue

That line isn't a command.  That's a line you add to an /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list file.

There is no command called deb it is a type of install file.

That line isn't a command.  That's a line you add to an /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list file.
Then run sudo apt update.  The  instructions for MongoDB's sources even state this isn't a command but something that goes in a file.

The way to add this file is to edit the file with a text editor (nano, vim, etc.) on the command line by doing nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list, pasting that line into the editor, and saving the file.
Alternatively, using echo 'deb [arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list will also do the same.

can you update the answer to include the commands needed to make the changes in the file directly from the terminal please?

@TalaatEtman It depends on implementation.  NORMALLY you'd use a text editor to create the file.  This also doesn't work on newer things that use the newer style to define repository entries, so I'll add it when I'm not innundated with other things to complete
